# Sliding element wont slide back down

Tags: javascript, dom-events, element

I'm making a form that has a checkbox that if checked will slide down some more options, and unchecked it will slide up.

The call to the function works one round I.E. slide down on check and up on uncheck but wont slide back up.

Please help me figure out how to make this work.

**NOTE: I don't know jQuery and don't want to invest the time to learn it at this point.

```
<form>
<table>
rows and cells here
THIS IS THE CHECKBOX TO SHOW HIDDEN TABLE --> <input type="checkbox" name="booking" class="field" value="booking" onclick="show_booking('booking',200,5)"/> Check here for booking
</table>
<table id="booking">
HIDDEN rows and cells here
</table>
</form>
```

******************JAVASCRIPT*********************

```
function show_booking(obj, heightOpen, heightClose){
    if(document.getElementById(obj).style.height <= 6 ){
        animateDown(document.getElementById(obj),heightOpen);
    }
    else {
        animateUp(document.getElementById(obj), heightClose);
        
    }
}

function animateDown(obj, height){
    
       var obj_height = obj.clientHeight;
       
       if(obj_height >= height){ return;}               
       else {
           obj.style.height = (obj_height + 5) + "px";
           setTimeout(function(){
               animateDown(obj, height);
           }, 25)
       }
}
    

function animateUp (obj, height){

       var obj_height = obj.style.height.substring(0,2);
        if(obj_height >= height){    obj.style.height = (obj_height - 5) + "px";
           setTimeout(function(){
               animateUp(obj, height);
           }, 200)}   
       else { return; }         
       }
```

Comment: if(document.getElementById(obj).style.height <= 6 )........ was worth getting out of bed this morning after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really trying to act based on whether the checkbox is checked, so why not use the checkbox's checked property:

```
<input onclick="show_booking.apply(this, ['booking', 200, 5])" type="checkbox" name="booking" class="field" value="booking"
```

`apply` sets the `this` value inside of the function to the first argument.  So inside of `show_booking` `this` will be the checkbox that was just clicked.  Now you can more simply write the function like:

```
function show_booking(obj, heightOpen, heightClose){
    if(this.checked) {
        animateDown(document.getElementById(obj),heightOpen);
    } 
    else {
        animateUp(document.getElementById(obj), heightClose);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo to you, the level of knowledge that the members of this site have never fails to amaze me. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, input.checked should be used to show/hide table. Instead of setting 'style.height' you should change style.display to block/none. Height might lead to troubles between different browsers.